# Use fopenmp in ghc to link with openmp

Tags: haskell, openmp, ghc

I have created a dynamic library that is using openmp. Whenever I want to use this lib I have to link with `-fopenmp`, so gcc or clang links correctly.

Now, I want to call this lib via FFI, but I have no clue, how to pass this `-fopenmp`-flag to ghc:

1. Static linking is not an opinion for openmp
2. If I link the library and ghc with the specific version of openmp (`-L/usr/lib/gcc/--GCCVERSION--/ -lgomp.h`) the linking does not complain but it is not activating openmp and ignoring the parameters

Does anyone has any clue how to *reenable* the `-fopenmp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I guess it is a simple naming problem:

gcc names it's openmp `gomp` while clang calls it `omp`.
So, I just had to change extra librarie to`omp` and now, it is compiling.